# Remove specific string or blank member from character vector

Tags: r, web-scraping, nlp

I am **scraping** https://www.transparency.org/news/pressreleases/year/2010 to retrieve header and details from each page. But along with header and details a telephone number and a blank string is coming in the retrieved list for every page.

[1] "See our simple, animated definitions of types of corruption and the ways to challenge it."
[2] "Judiciary - Commenting on Justice Bean’s sentencing in the BAE Systems’ Tanzania case, Transparency International UK welcomed the Judge’s stringent remarks concerning BAE Systems’ past conduct."
[3] "            "
[4] "+49 30 3438 20 666"

I have tried with following codes but they didn't worked.

html %>% str_remove('+49 30 3438 20 666') %>% str_remove('      ').

How these elements can be removed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you want to drop all lines that start with a + and end with a number:

```
dd <- c(
 "See our simple, animated definitions of types of corruption and the ways to challenge it."
, "Judiciary - Commenting on Justice Bean’s sentencing in the BAE Systems’ Tanzania case, Transparency International UK welcomed the Judge’s stringent remarks concerning BAE Systems’ past conduct."
," "
, "+49 30 3438 20 666")

c <- dd[!grepl("^\\+.*\\d*$",dd)]
```

You can also use `\\s` (one empty space) and `\\d{2}` (2 numbers) to have an exact match, to be on the safe side, if all numbers have the same format. Note that you can also use it in str_remove, with the end result beig an empty string. grep instead returns as logical vector that subsets your string.

If you want to delete also all empty lines

```
dd[!grepl("^\\s*$",dd)]
```

Note that you can do both at the same time by using "|":

```
dd[!grepl("^\\+.*\\d*$|^\\s*$",dd)]
```

You can get familiar with regex here: https://regex101.com/

Comment: Great, I am able to get rid of the telephone number with your suggestion. But still unable to remove the " " element from the list. Any suggestion for that?

Comment: Thanks very much. Your suggestion worked perfectly and removed all the empty elements.

Answer (score 2):

Is it because you failed to escape the `+` sign?

From this [cheatsheet](https://rstudio.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/RegExCheatsheet.pdf),

> Metacharacters (. * + etc.) can be used as
>   literal characters by escaping them. Characters
>   can be escaped using \ or by enclosing them
>   in \Q...\E.

```r
s = "+49 30 3438 20 666"
str_remove(s, "\\+49 30 3438 20 666")
# ""
```

Comment: Great, I am able to get rid of the telephone number with your suggestion. Thanks for the cheatsheet. But still unable to remove the " " element from the list.

Comment: See `purrr::keep` or `discard` or `compact`